# Browser doesn't recognize html files written with node file system

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, server-side-rendering

I'm building an application using React an Apollo 2 and I'm trying to write a script to generate static html files for server-side rendering.

I'm currently using this logic to render my React component on the server and it's working fine:

```
export default (Page) => (req, res) => {
    const App = (
        <ApolloProvider client={client(fetch)}>
            <Main>
                <Page />
            </Main>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );

    getDataFromTree(App).then(() => {
        const data = {
            html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App),
            seo: { title: "Home", description: "" }
        };
        res.render("index", { data });
    });
}
```

But I wanted to generate the `.html` files so I could serve them statically, without running this method every time. I tried to compile the result of `renderToString` to an `.ejs` file and then write to a file using `fs`, but it didn't work. This is the code:

```
const component = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App);
const template = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'landing_template.ejs'), 'utf-8'));
const html = template({ component });

fs.writeFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "../views/landing.ejs"),
    html, 
    err => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else console.log("done.");
});
```

The file was written successfully but If I open my Page Source the part added by the compile method is grayed out and seems to be ignored:

[image]

I also tried just reading the file and replacing the string using `.replace` and inserting a dummy `div`, but it's always the same result.

```
// using compile
const template = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'landing_template.ejs'), 'utf-8'));
const html = template({ component });

const template = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'landing_template.ejs'), 'utf-8'));
const html = template({ component: "<div>teste</div>" });

// using readFile
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'landing_template.ejs'), 'utf-8');
const html = template.replace("<%- component %>", component);

const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'landing_template.ejs'), 'utf-8');
const html = template.replace("<%- component %>", "<div>teste</div>");

// maybe this is the problem?
fs.writeFile(
    path.join(__dirname, "../views/landing.ejs"),
    html,
    { encoding: "utf8" },
    err => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else console.log("done.");
});
```

[image]

I guess the browser is not recognizing this new text as HTML and failing to parse it. Does any one know a way I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem with the HTML code is the <script> tag is not closed. See replicated bug: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/3x5pb4oL/ and the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/3x5pb4oL/3/

Comment: script tags are not self closing tags. Even if there isn't anything in between the `<script></script>` you cannot just use `<script/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a cool idea! This is probably happening because, as you mentioned, the browser is not recognizing the fact that you are sending html. Try explicitly setting the `Content-Type` header to `text/html` before calling render:

```
export default (Page) => (req, res) => {
    const App = (
        <ApolloProvider client={client(fetch)}>
            <Main>
                <Page />
            </Main>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );

    getDataFromTree(App).then(() => {
        const data = {
            html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App),
            seo: { title: "Home", description: "" }
        };
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        res.render("index", { data });
    });
}
```

**Edit**:

Ah I see it now! You cannot self-close `<script>` tags in HTML unfortunately, and this is tripping the browser up. Close the script tag in your header like so:

```
<script async src="/build/app.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. :/ Checked in the browser and the content-type is text/html, but stills fails to parse it.

Comment: @ThiagoLoddi Ah I see the problem now! Updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

`<script />` is wrong. You have to use this:

```
<script src="URL"></script>
```